# loading a Unity Vuforia Project in a Subview in Android throws Fatal Exception

Tags: android, 3d, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I'm building an Augmented Reality application using `Unity` with the `Vuforia SDK`. I've successfully built my project directly from `Unity` to `Android`. Now I'm trying to run my unity project in a subview of an Android project which I have written in Eclipse. I've imported my project as a library from Unity to Eclipse. I've set all the libraries correctly (external jars etc). Below is the code of my `onCreate` method where the unity project should be loaded in a `FrameLayout` named framelayout2

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

import com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARPlayerNativeActivity;
import com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARUnityPlayer;
import com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARPlayerProxyActivity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public QCARUnityPlayer m_UnityPlayer;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    m_UnityPlayer = new QCARUnityPlayer(this);
    int glesMode = m_UnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    m_UnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);     

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    layout.addView(m_UnityPlayer.getView(), 0, lp);

}
```

But the project crashes with the following error in the LogCat:

```
11-16 13:35:06.676: I/QCAR(11889): onSurfaceCreated
11-16 13:35:06.676: W/dalvikvm(11889): No implementation found for native Lcom/qualcomm/QCAR/QCAR;.onSurfaceCreated ()V
11-16 13:35:06.686: W/dalvikvm(11889): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c631f8)
11-16 13:35:06.686: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2050): setHidden true
11-16 13:35:06.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11889): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 507
11-16 13:35:06.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11889): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: onSurfaceCreated
11-16 13:35:06.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11889):    at com.qualcomm.QCAR.QCAR.onSurfaceCreated(Native Method)
11-16 13:35:06.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11889):    at com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARUnityPlayer.onSurfaceCreated(QCARUnityPlayer.java:39)
11-16 13:35:06.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11889):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1446)
11-16 13:35:06.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11889):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
11-16 13:35:06.686: W/ActivityManager(2050):   Force finishing activity com.samsung.arapp.gr/.MainActivity
```

Has anyone attempted anything similar? Can you please help me?

Comment: Have you copied over the manifest file which has all the permissions?

Comment: Yes I have but I think it has something to to with the NDK part of vuforia

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [this](https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/overlaying-androi-data-over-qcarunityplayer) guy had the same problem. Check out the steps he took [here](https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/unity-how-can-i-extend-unitys-android-activity)